# Magento2 layered navigation product count for bundle items

Tags: magento2, filter

There is a way to exclude from the count, in the layered navigation, child product that have the filter attribute?
For example: I have a product A with attribute region set to "tuscany", and I have also a bundle B which contains the product A, but the bundle doesn't have the region attribute set. What I get in layered navigation for region filter "tuscany" is 2, but I don't want to include in the count the bundle's child items.

Comment: No clue so far?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:
Ive created a plugin on the indexer

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Indexer\AbstractIndexer">
    <plugin name="excludeBundleFromCount" type="Vendor\FilteredNavigation\Plugin\Indexer\AbstractIndexer"/>
</type>
```

and the class:

```
namespace Vendor\FilteredNavigation\Plugin\Indexer;

class AbstractIndexer
{
    public function aroundGetRelationsByParent(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Indexer\AbstractIndexer $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $parentIds
    ) {
        return [];
    }
}
```

so all the save on bundle item doesn't create an index entry for the attribute.

Not the beatiful and elegant way but it does its job.